# What is an example of an error that tflint will catch that `terraform init` will not error on?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to test a pipeline change that will run tflint automatically, but I'm struggling to find an example of an error that won't prevent `terraform init` from completing without errors but will be caught by `tflint --module`. My goal is to prove that tflint is running is running in the pipeline and will fail any pipeline that finds linting errors. Any ideas?

I know there must be lots of examples, or tflint wouldn't exist - but I'm not running across them right now.

Examples of things I've tried so far: tflint doesn't catch white space or using dashes when underlines are more 'correct' (or is this a config issue on my part?), `terraform init` doesn't tolerate single quotes or misnamed modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the default [rules](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-terraform/blob/main/docs/rules/README.md) for `tflint`. Most of these rules will have an example of how to trigger it and remediate it. A simple one you could use is the `terraform_comment_syntax` [rule](https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-terraform/blob/main/docs/rules/terraform_comment_syntax.md).

You can trigger it by using a `// comment` inside a `*.tf` file.